# Node ES6 Import and Typescript ES6 Import Aren't the Same

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, atom-editor

Using `atom-typescript` and `ts-node` I'm able to run the typescript source directly without first needing to compile it. However, when I do compile it and I try to import the same file from source and the dist they appear in different formats.

Here is my `index.ts` file:

```
import {_for} from './for';
import {_forEach} from './forEach';
import {_while} from './while';

export let PromiseChain = {
  for:      _for,
  forEach:  _forEach,
  while:    _while
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
"use strict";
var for_1 = require('./for');
var forEach_1 = require('./forEach');
var while_1 = require('./while');
exports.PromiseChain = {
    for: for_1._for,
    forEach: forEach_1._forEach,
    while: while_1._while
};
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

From my test file I try to first import the PromiseChain object from `../dist/index` and then the same object from `./index`. It looks like this-

```
import * as PromiseChainDist from '../dist/index';
import * as PromiseChainSrc from './index';
```

Issue is. Dist contains exported members `for`, `forEach`, and `while`. Whereas the Src contains `PromiseChain`.

This can be seen in the following screenshots-

[image]

[image]

Should I expect them to behave the same? Should I want them to behave the same? I'd like to be able to do this with the dist-

```
/// ES5
var PromiseChain = require('promise-chain');
PromiseChain.for(...);

/// ES6
import {PromiseChain} from 'promise-chain';
PromiseChain.for(...);
```

Why can I do this with the src but not the dist?

**Edit:**

The plot thickens. Just testing the dist import. It looks like this-

[image]

But this was saying `PromiseChain.for` was not a function. After logging PromiseChain it get this!-

```
{ PromiseChain: 
   { for: [Function: _for],
     forEach: [Function: _forEach],
     while: [Function: _while] } }
```

So that would mean it should look like this- `PromiseChain.PromiseChain.for` which is undesirable. But still, I am unable to import PromiseChain directly.

[image]

This definitely seems like a bug.

**Edit Edit:**

If I structure it like this-

```
export = {
  for: _for,
  forEach: _forEach,
  while: _while
}
```

The `import * as PromiseChain from ...` does work. I still want to be able to `import {PromiseChain}` though..

Comment: The dist version is behaving weird, this might be a bug.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the desired ES5 and ES6 behaviours for the same file.

Comment: If I just stick to ES6 and abandon ES5 do you know why it's not behaving the same between pointing to the src and dist index? `import ... from 'promise-chain'`

Comment: What does `../dist/index.d.ts` look like?